# Find the integer pixel position of an element relative to the viewport or document: getBoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The function [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) can return non-integer values. For example, something like:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 5%; width: 66.666%"></div>
```

almost always have non-integer values for the `left` and `width` values of `getBoundingClientRect` . You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/QW91gy3hPMagSECQswdM?p=preview , with an example value of its left value being 32.796875 (in Chrome at least).

How these non-integer values are actually rendered on the screen I believe is [browser-dependent](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/).

So, how can I programatically find the whole-pixel coordinates of an element on-screen?

Edit: ideally without jQuery, and ideally without walking the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

a lot of modern browsers use subpixel rendering, so most likely there exist no whole-pixel coordinates..

but with jQuery you can do something like this to get an array [left, top, width, height] relative to document space:

```
function bounds(el) {

    var $el = $(el);
    if (!$el.is(':visible')) {
        return null;
    }

    var offset = $el.offset();
    return [offset.left, offset.top, $el.outerWidth(), $el.outerHeight()];
}
```

relative to Viewport:

```
function boundsVp(el) {

    var $el = $(el);
    if (!$el.is(':visible')) {
        return null;
    }

    var $win = $(window);
    var offset = $el.offset();
    return [offset.left - $win.scrollLeft(), offset.top - $win.scrollTop(), $el.outerWidth(), $el.outerHeight()];
}
```

you might be interested in [jQuery.fracs](https://larsjung.de/jquery-fracs/) as well..